# How can I override the limitations of boolean PhotoViewAttacher onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)?

Tags: java, android, android-photoview

`PhotoViewAttacher`'s `boolean onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)` prevents my `OnSingleFlingListener`'s `onFling` method from being called unless the current scale is the minimun.

I implemented `OnSingleFlingListener` from `com.github.chrisbanes.photoview`. However, since the `onFling` method is only package visible, `PhotoViewAttacher`'s `onFling` method gets called first. `PhotoViewAttacher.onFling` prevents my `onFling` method from being called when `scale > DEFAULT_MIN_SCALE`. I need mine called unless `scale > getMediumScale()`. (`scale == getMediumScale()` when my image's width matches the window's width.) How can I get around this? Do I need to make my own copy of the entire `PhotoView` package and modify `OnSingleFlingListener.onFling` to be public?

My code:

```
public class BasicViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DownloadCallback, OnSingleFlingListener {
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        . . . 
        return true;
    }
```

OnSingleFlingListener:

```
package com.github.chrisbanes.photoview;
public interface OnSingleFlingListener {
    boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY);
}
```

PhotoViewAttacher:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    if (mSingleFlingListener != null) {
        if (getScale() > DEFAULT_MIN_SCALE) {
            return false;
        }
        . . . 
        return mSingleFlingListener.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want my `onFling` called when `getScale() <= getMediumScale()`. Instead, my `onFling` method is called only when `getScale() == DEFAULT_MIN_SCALE`.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to work around it.

1. I cloned the PhotoView package.
2. I copied its source into my own package.
3. I changed the one line mentioned above (and added a fraction to prevent floating point error):

   ```
   if(getScale() > getMediumScale() + .01f) {
       return false;
   }
   ```